# MS Access query WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been looking around and haven't been able to make this work out.

I have two tables resultant from two queries

```
SELECT [Account Combination].[Account Number] & [Account Combination].[Cost Center] & [Account Combination].Amount as Val1 FROM [Account Combination];
```

AND

```
SELECT [Account Combination].[Account Number] & [Account Combination].[Cost Center] & [Account Combination].Amount AS Val1 FROM [Account Information] INNER JOIN ([Cost Center] INNER JOIN [Account Combination] ON [Cost Center].[Cost Center Number] = [Account Combination].[Cost Center]) ON [Account Information].[Account Number] = [Account Combination].[Account Number];
```

Table1 has 1800 rows and Table2 has 1600. I would like to read which are found in Table1 and not found in Table2, the 200.

I have tried the Table1 NOT EXISTS Tabel2 but haven't been able to make it work properly as I get syntax error all the time.

Thank for your time,
Simon.

Comment: tag your question properly to get right answer quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `LEFT OUTER JOIN` along with `WHERE` condition like below to get this done

```
select t1.*
from (SELECT [Account Combination].[Account Number] & [Account Combination].[Cost Center] & [Account Combination].Amount as Val1 
FROM [Account Combination]) t1
left join (
SELECT [Account Combination].[Account Number] & [Account Combination].[Cost Center] & [Account Combination].Amount AS Val1 
FROM [Account Information] INNER JOIN ([Cost Center] INNER JOIN [Account Combination] 
ON [Cost Center].[Cost Center Number] = [Account Combination].[Cost Center]) 
ON [Account Information].[Account Number] = [Account Combination].[Account Number]) t2 
on t1.Val1 = t2.Val1 
where t2.Val1 is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to : [This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52506888/6580792)

It answers the question how to use NOT EXISTS.
I observed by the way, that the IS NULL clause is faster.