# Using WHERE NOT EXISTS in MS Access SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that matches a field from a query to another field from a table.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CarriersToSend.Carrier, [Dual Year Carrier Report].TPA_CARRIER
FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] INNER JOIN CarriersToSend ON [Dual Year Carrier Report].TPA_CARRIER = CarriersToSend.Carrier;
```

It returns the values that match in the Carrier field of the CarriersToSend query and the TPA_CARRIER field of [Dual Year Carrier Report].

I then need to return the values that are in the Carrier field of the CarriersToSend query that do not appear in the above query.  I think it would be something like a WHERE NOT EXISTS QUERY.  I put one together below, but it is not returning anything and I cant figure out why.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

```
SELECT DISTINCT EE_First, EE_LAST
FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT DISTINCT CarriersToSend.Carrier, [Dual Year Carrier Report].TPA_CARRIER
FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] INNER JOIN CarriersToSend ON [Dual Year Carrier Report].TPA_CARRIER = CarriersToSend.Carrier;)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your semi colon should come after the closing parenthesis.
Apart from that, your query will logically never return any records.
That's because your subquery returns a result and then you are trying to return a result that doesn't match the result of the subquery. This will logically result in a false condition.
Try this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EE_First, EE_LAST
FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report]
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT '1'
FROM CarriersToSend INNER JOIN [Dual Year Carrier Report] ON 
CarriersToSend.Carrier = [Dual Year Carrier Report].TPA_CARRIER
);
```

Comment: I got the same result as my second query above (which was an empty set)

Answer (score 2):

Your `NOT EXISTS` with subquery didn't connect with the main query, so that didn't return any result.

You can try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT EE_First, EE_LAST
FROM [Dual Year Carrier Report] t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM CarriersToSend t2
    WHERE t1.TPA_CARRIER = t2.Carrier
)
```